On the solution sets to the ODE $(a^2-1)Q''(a) + \left(3a-\frac{d-1}{a} \right)Q'(a) + \frac{3}{4}Q(a)=0$
Looking for self-similar, radial solutions to a certain nonlinear wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ leads to studying the following linear ODE in the self-similar variable $a\in[0,1)$:
$$(a^2-1)Q''(a) + \left(3a-\frac{d-1}{a} \right)Q'(a) + \frac{3}{4}Q(a)=0$$
Mathematica tells me that the solution set is spanned by
$$\operatorname{span}\left\{ {}_2F_1(1/4, 3/4, d/2, a^2),a^{2-d}i^{2-d}{}_2F_1(5/4-d/2, 7/4-d/2, 2-d/2, a^2)\right\},$$
where ${}_2F_1$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function.
I have two questions:

The second hypergeometric function is undefined for even $d\ge 4$ as then $2-d/2$ is a nonpositive integer. What happens then to the set of solutions?

For odd $d\ge 3$, by checking each case individually on Mathematica, I want to conjecture that the hypergeometric solutions simplify so that the set of solutions is given by
$$\sum_{\pm}c_{\pm}a^{2-d}(1\pm a)^{d/2-1}P^d_{\pm}(a),$$
where $P^d_\pm(a)$ is a polynomial that is non-vanishing at $a\in\{-1, 1\}$ of degree $d/2-3/2\in \mathbb{N}_0$. Is this conjecture true or false?


EDIT: @Fred Hucht's comment seems to answer Question 1. However, the Legendre functions are themselves expressed as hypergeometric functions and so Question 2 is still seemingly unresolved.

Seems that the last term should read $\frac 3 4 Q(a)$ instead of $\frac 3 4 Q'(a)$ (also in the title).

Next, you can substitute $a\mapsto \sqrt{b}$, $Q(a)\mapsto f(b)$ to get
$4 (b-1) b f''(b)+(8 b-2 d) f'(b)+\frac{3}{4}f(b) = 0$, with solutions in terms of Legendre $P$ and $Q$. These solutions are also defined for $d\geq4$.

Q1
See my comment above.
Q2
For odd $d\geq 3$ the solutions are related to
https://oeis.org/A067001. With boundary condition $Q(\pm 1)=1$ and $n=\frac{d-3}{2} \in\mathbb{N}_0$, they can be simplified to
\begin{align}
Q_{n}(a)=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt 2\,a^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n} &
\binom{n}{k} \, {}_2F_1(\tfrac 1 2,-k;-2n;2) \times{}\\
&{}\times\left[
 (1+a)^{n+\frac 1 2} (-a)^k - (1-a)^{n+\frac 1 2} a^k
\right] \, .
\end{align}

Thank you for this answer. Can you add a bit more detail on you derived this expression for the solution?

I am quite busy at the moment. Using Mathematica, I solved the ODE for odd $d\geq 3$ and well-defined boundary conditions, and looked up the polynomials in OEIS, with hit https://oeis.org/A067001. The given sum formula was simplified to the above answer. It can be verified by insertion into the ODE. Note that the ${}_2F_1(\cdot)$ simplify to rational constants. I did not construct the solution set, but that should be straightforward. I hope that helps!

Thank you, this is very helpful indeed!
